# How to describe a column in a table - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I just created a table

```
create table TestSchema.TestConfiguration
(
    SomeId int not null,
    LegacyColumnName bit default 0
);
```

Now I am trying to describe the table in the following way:

```
  exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
        @name = N'MS_Description ', 
        @value = N'My Organisation's Configuration table', 
        @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
        @level0name = N'TestSchema', 
        @level1type = N'TABLE',
        @level1name = N'TestConfiguration',
        @level2type = N'COLUMN',
        @level2name = N'LegacyColumnName';
```

I want to describe here in plain words what `LegacyColumnName` column stands for, something like `@level2description`..

How do I do that ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Here's an idea using extended properties http://geekswithblogs.net/TimothyK/archive/2014/02/27/add-column-descriptions-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: @SilverSkin: Thanks. But it doesn't say about describing a column. It talks about `sp_addextendedproperty`

Comment: Why aren't you happy with your current code, seems good to me ? If it is not working, just take care of escaping the `'` like in `Organization's`.

Comment: As I understood it the example uses sp_addExtendedProperty to add column descriptions, but maybe not in the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the query as shown in your question

```
 exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
        @name = N'MS_Description ', 
        @value = N'My Organisation's Configuration table', 
        @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
        @level0name = N'TestSchema', 
        @level1type = N'TABLE',
        @level1name = N'TestConfiguration',
        @level2type = N'COLUMN',
        @level2name = N'LegacyColumnName';
```

then, `My Organisation's Configuration table` will become the description of the `LegacyColumnName` column.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, then the descriptions for the `TestSchema`, `TestConfiguration`, `LegacyColumnName` are all same ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Raj's excellent answer, something below extends that answer:

Question: 
So, if I understand correctly, then the descriptions for the TestSchema, TestConfiguration, LegacyColumnName are all same ?

Answer: 
      No

The following code just describes the purpose of 'Legacy Column Name'.

```
exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
        @name = N'MS_Description ', 
        @value = N'Legacy Column is used for blah blah blah', 
        @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
        @level0name = N'TestSchema', 
        @level1type = N'TABLE',
        @level1name = N'TestConfiguration',
        @level2type = N'COLUMN',
        @level2name = N'LegacyColumnName';
```

If you want to describe the table, then the following would do so.

```
exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
        @name = N'MS_Description ', 
        @value = N'My Organisation's Configuration table', 
        @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
        @level0name = N'TestSchema', 
        @level1type = N'TABLE',
        @level1name = N'TestConfiguration';
```

If you want to describe each and every column (or table, etc.,) you need to have explicit calls to ***sys.sp_addextendedproperty***.